# How make mobile app google analytics show new users source/referral

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I'm successfully running google analytics for my mobile app and it shows new users , sessions .. etc, however I want to know if the new user is from a direct link install to my app on google play page (with referrals ?) or from a search result in google play store . Can any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Campaign Measurement, which allows you to see which campaigns, websites, and other apps are referring users to Google Play Store to download your app.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Comment: When I use referral link to trigger Google play and install the app, the GA increase: one new user and one session from (direct) / (none), and one session from my referral source. How can I explain it?